# Is the assembly dll signed when we create key and hit 'build'?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

we are trying to sign an assembly dll from VS2010. To sign, we go to the signing tab and create a new key. Then, build the solution. A DLL is generated.

Has VS already signed this DLL? or do we need to run some coomand like snk on the DLL file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Has VS already signed this DLL?

Yes, unless you specifically request [delay signing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t07a3dye%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Note that this means that a configuration which specifies signing *requires* the key to be present, which doesn't mesh well with the key being a private resource with limited access. Delay signing is one option, but another is to have multiple configurations where some produce signed assemblies and some produce unsigned assemblies. See the [Noda Time project file](https://code.google.com/p/noda-time/source/browse/src/NodaTime/NodaTime.csproj) for example, where we have "Release", "Signed Release", "Release Portable" and "Signed Release Portable" (as well as debug configurations). The signed builds are only used when actually releasing a version publicly; most development is performed using the unsignged configurations.

Comment: OK, thanks, one more thing.. This key is generated by me. Is this a correct practice to sign an DLL file with my key (generated)? I have read about public/private key and certificates, etc. What I am doing is generating it myself. I am not purchasing a certificate. Is this correct?

Comment: @NachiketKamat: As far as I'm aware, that's fine. I'm not an expert on these matters though :) Note that the snk *is* a public/private key pair, and you may want to publish the public key (elsewhere) so that anyone who wants to can validate that your signed assemblies are signed with the correct private key.

Comment: OK please let me know if I got you correctly. --> When we go to project properties in VS and create the .pfx file and checkmark the sign assembly; VS will sign the dll when we build the solution. Correct? The, you say that we must ship the .dll as well as .pfx to client. .dll has already been signed by VS. The sole purpose of shipping the .pfx is to check whether this is the same signed dll. Correct? What is the procedure to check this?

Comment: @NachiketKamat: I haven't used pfx files - only snks. It sounds like you shouldn't ship the pfx itself, but instead you can specify a public key or public key token in readable form on your website, or something similar. Anyone who wanted to could then check that it matches what's on the assembly using `sn -T [assembly]` or `sn -Tp [assembly]`

Comment: Thank you very much! Appreciated. Can you tell me how do I get the token or key value so I can put share it with clients? Suppose I use .snk.